Error obteniendo query parameter en express
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación NodeJS con express, en la cual necesito capturar los query que estoy enviando en la url. Cuando ejecuto la app en local todo funciona de forma correcta. Sin embargo al ejecutar la aplicacion en produccion no estoy capturando los query parameters. La aplicacion de produccion la tengo desplegada en un VPS con Ubuntu Server, en el cual estoy utilizando nginx como proxy con certbot para manejar el ssl. Para ejecutar la aplicacion estoy utilizando pm2.
A continuacion les comparte parte de la configuracion del servidor con express:
import { Server as HttpServer, createServer } from 'http';

import express, { Application } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';
import path from 'path';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { Server as SocketServer } from "socket.io";

import { 
    orderConfirmRouter,
    // ... resto de importaciones de los router
}from '../routes/index.js';

import { socketOnConnection } from '../sockets/socket.js';
import { dbConnection } from '../database/config.js';

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export default class Server{
    private app  : Application;
    private port : string;
    private server: HttpServer;
    private io: SocketServer;

    private path = {
        orderConfirm: '/api/confirmation',
        // resto de rutas...
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT ?? '8080';
        this.server = createServer( this.app );
        this.io = new SocketServer( this.server, { allowEIO3: true } );
 
        // conectar a base de datos
        this.conectarDB();

        // middlewares
        this.middlewares();

        // rutas de mi applicacion
        this.routes();

        // sockets
        this.sockets();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    async conectarDB(){
        await dbConnection();
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    middlewares(){
        // CORS
        this.app.use( cors({
            origin : '*',
            credentials: true,
            exposedHeaders: [ 'x-token']
        }) );

        // parseo y lectura del body
        // con esto especifico que el body viene en formato json
        this.app.use( express.json() );
        // this.app.use( express.query({}));

        // directorio publico
        this.app.use( express.static( 'public' ) );

        // File upload - Carga de archivos
        this.app.use(fileUpload({
            useTempFiles : true,
            tempFileDir : '/tmp/',
            createParentPath: true
        }));
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    routes()  {
        this.app.use( this.path.orderConfirm, orderConfirmRouter );
        // resto de las rutas que tengo definidas...

        const __dirname = path.resolve();
        this.app.get('/*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/', 'index.html')); }); 
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    listen(){
        this.server.listen( this.port, () =>{         
            console.log( 'Servidor corriendo en puerto: ', this.port );
        })
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
}

A continuacion les muestro la definicion de la ruta:
import { Router } from 'express';

import { getOrderConfimation, postOrderConfimation } from '../controllers/order-confirmation.js';

const router = Router();

router.get('/',[], getOrderConfimation);

router.post('/',[], postOrderConfimation);

export default router;

// Controlador de la ruta
import { Response, Request } from "express";

// -----------------------------------------------------
export const postOrderConfimation = async (req : Request, res : Response) =>{
    const { id, key } = req.query;
    console.log( 'Params: ', req.params );
    console.log( 'Query: ', req.query );
    console.log( 'Body: ', req.body );
    console.log( 'header: ', req.header );
    console.log(id, key);
    // console.log( 'req: ', req );
    
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------
export const getOrderConfimation = async (req : Request, res : Response) =>{
    console.log('GET confirmation')
    console.log( 'Params: ', req.params );
    console.log( 'Query: ', req.query );
    console.log( 'Body: ', req.body );
    console.log( 'header: ', req.header );
    console.log( req.url, req.originalUrl );
    // console.log('raw headers:', req.rawHeaders);
    // console.log( 'req: ', req );
    
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------

Aqui he probado tanto por GET como por POST y no recibo los query parameter, por ejemplo, haciendo pruebas con postman con la url {{url}}/api/confirmation?id=123&key=abc123, tanto el id como el key los recibo como undefined.
Espero que me puedan ayudar a encontrar una solucion.
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.
